# Getting firestore data from a Google Cloud Function with array-contains-any

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

A web page calls a Firebase function that should get several records from a Firestore collection, Everything runs without error but no data is returned. When I run the query in the page directly (not via the function), the right data is returned.

In the web page:

```
var getUserConfigFiles = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getUserConfigFiles');
        
getUserConfigFiles()
    .then((result) => {
         console.log("Yay - Firebase result ===>",result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.warn("error",error.code,error.message,error.details)
    });
```

In index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const db = admin.firestore();
```

Then the function itself:

```
exports.getUserConfigFiles = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        return {"status": "error", "code": 499, "message": "The function must be called while authenticated"};
    }
    
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const email = context.auth.token.email;

    var outcome = {"status": "OK", "code": 200, "requestor": uid, "email": email, "configfiles":[]};
    
    // search on either the user's userid or their email
    outcome.searcharray = [uid];
    if (email) {
        outcome.searcharray.push(email);
    }
    
    return db.collection("configfiles").where("memberAttached", "array-contains-any", outcome.searcharray)
        .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    outcome.configfiles.push({"tokenid": doc.id, "data-all": doc.data()});
                })

                // next row is returning the object just to see if it's there
                outcome.querySnapshot = querySnapshot;
                // 

                return (outcome);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return ({"status": "error", "code": 402, "message": error,"requestor": uid});
            });
    
 });
```

Everything works, the result returns a querySnapshot. Except, there is no data, .configfiles should have a hundred or so rows. If I run the  `db.collection("configfiles").where("memberAttached...` portion just in the web page, data is returned.

[image]

I have searched and tried many approaches but I'm obviously missing something fundamental. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect the `outcome.querySnapshot = querySnapshot` line is causing problems, as `querySnapshot` is not a JSON object and thus can't be returned. I recommend removing that line, and trying again.

If that doesn't solve the problem, can you add some logging, and see if the code ever reaches inside the `then`?

Comment: That put me on the right track! I couldn't see any comments in the firebase console so I went looking for them. The basic issue was that the functions were being run by the emulator but the data was in firestore. When I turned off the function emulator, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it our @AndrewNZ 